# Eclipse C compilation issue

Tags: c, eclipse, compilation

I 've built a C program in eclipse it was going fine with the compilation but at some point I changed a part of my code and then the console kept having the same output no matter how many times i build it or run it or change the code once more.So I erased the binary file hoping to start from new but then it keeps popping out binary not found.What should I do please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: When posting a question about compilation errors, then it helps a lot to include the *complete* and *unedited* error log. The code in question, with the erroneous lines marked, will also help a lot. And please *edit the question* to include it.

Comment: Now it says that my .exe has encountered a problem,because the program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist.So how do I overpass that, I tried to make a new project but it says binary not found even though I build it so I searched the debug file and it has a subdir.mrk in which a it has a false line written "@echo 'Building fil : $<'"and hovering it to see the error it says "@echo 'Building file:First prerequisite of the rule' so what might be the deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a compilation or linking or `make` error. Check the Problems view in Eclipse (you should also see red squiggles, and red crosses, wherever there is a compilation error).

Comment: I manged to overcome my code errors from the Problems tab but in my new project, but what happened in the first place why it compiled the same things all the time even though I changed the code is that typical from eclipse when it has errors?

Comment: What happens is it doesn't overwrite the last version, if it failed to compile. This is completely normal. The reason why normally Eclipse users never have this problem, is Eclipse will warn "errors exist in project" if you try to run the program from Eclipse, and it has compilation errors. At least for Java programs, anyway, I don't know about C programs.