# building file error in eclipse building c progrram

Tags: c

I'm using eclipse to and executing c program and it is giving me error that...
`@echo 'building error: first prerequisite of rule'`
i'm not getting why this error is displaying.
i'm executing program in c and the error is:

Comment: the project is not making binaries.
can anyone help?

Comment: It is impossible to help you with that vague problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888841/eclipse-c-compilation-issue)

If you're on Windows I suggest using Visual Studio, or Code::Blocks. You don't have to, just my preferences.

EDIT:

Also, if you want me to help you solve your problem, can you maybe post your code, or tell us what version of Eclipse your using. Try to include as much information as possible.